# How should my Get method look like - MVC 4?

Tags: c#, ajax, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my API controller's Get method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public MyTable GetMyTable(byte id, string langId)
    {
        MyTable mytable;
        if (id == 0)
        {
            mytable = db.MyTables.Find(langId);
        }
        else
        {
            mytable = db.MyTables.Find(id, langId);
        }

        if (mytable == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return mytable;
    }
```

It has two keys, so a composite key. The DbSet.Find() method requires that both MyTable.ID and MyTable.LanguageId be specified.

My model for this table looks like:

```
[Table("MyTable", Schema = "MyScheme")]
public class MyTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string MyCode { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public string LanguageId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public byte LevelId { get; set; }

    public string ConceptName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to list all entries by given language id, but without specific id given.
I also want to be able to get single entry with id and langId.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just a simple `Where(x => x.Lang == langId)` clause? Of course you have to change the return type.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma What will I get in my browser if I change it to IQueriable? Also the expression inside complains, it cannot convert from string to bool. What should I do?

Comment: I believe your issue arises from an architectural problem. What do you expect this method should do? You may return a collection or a single entity (if you use `IHttpActionResult` as return type), but this way you'll have to manage two different return types in the client (a json array or a json object). I truly suggest you to split this logic into two different actions (with two different URIs).

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Yes I also wanted to have two Get methods, one with just langId and one with (id, langId), but I am so noob with C# that I don't know where to start. Btw I added my model class. Hopefully it helps

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Yes, it works with the where clause, but with two methods. The one with only langId should return IQueriable<MyTable> and the one with id and langId should return single MyTable instance.

Comment: Your approach with two methods is better than the one inside your question. What I do not understand is if that is a Web Api controller or a MVC controller. Can you clarify what are you using?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I don't know well C#, neither Entity Framework 4, nor Razor rendering engine. Therefore I decided a RESTful service with MVC 4 would do the job. Clean HTML inside CSHTML page, clean JavaScript inside a JS file and all I do is create AJAX calls with jQuery. Therfore I created API controllers. I call them with `http://localhost:port/api/controllername`. I guess I am using Web API controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working code:

```
    // GET api/MyTable?langid=mk-MK
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<MyTable> GetMyTable(string langid)
    {
        IQueryable<MyTable> mytable = db.MyTables.Where(x => x.LanguageId == langid);
        if (mytable == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return mytable;
    }

    // GET api/MyTable?id=5&langid=mk-MK
    [HttpGet]
    public MyTable GetMyTable(byte id, string langid)
    {
        MyTable mytable = db.MyTables.Find(id, langid);

        if (mytable == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return mytable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetMyTable(string langId)
{
   var mytable = db.MyTables.Find(langId);
   return Json(mytable);
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetMyTable(byte id, string langId)
{
    MyTable mytable = db.MyTables.Find(id, langId);
    if (mytable == null)
    {
        return Json(new {Message = "NullreferenceExeption"})
    }
    return Json(mytable);
}
```

Comment: You will need JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in order for this to not throw an exception. For example: return Json(myTable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Yes, I know it looks easy. I tried similar thing with two get methods, both return MyTable object with different parameter list. The problem is, I get ArgumentException when I call db.MyTables.Find(langId): The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
Parameter name: keyValues

Comment: @Vlad Then you answered your own question. The Find method expect a unique key - it returns a single find not a list of elements. In your case unique key is composed on 2 values. When you give it only one it fails. You probably need something else to get a list where LangId = someValue. See what other methods you have available to you on db.MyTables...

Comment: @Marko No, I didn't answer my question. Yes Find() might be for a single result. I don't know how to send comparison clause to the DbSet.Where() statement. It complains, it cannot convert string to bool. Please read top coments.

Comment: Wait. I had just one "=", it needed two "==", so: "x=>x.LanguageId == langId". Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 queries which return different result sets. One returns a collection the other one returns a single result. I'm not going to get into describing how a proper RESTful response should look in api controller. That's a different topic. But if we look at what you have so far it should be like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public MyTable GetMyTable(byte id, string langId)
{
    List<MyTable> results = new List<MyTable>();
    if (id == 0)
    {
        results = db.MyTables.Where(x => x.LanguageId == langid).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        var find = db.MyTables.Find(id, langId);
        if (find != null) results.Add(find);
    }
    return results;
}
```

This way the results always come back as a list and if find is used for unique entry find then you get back a list with a single element.